# Troubles while trying to use getElementsByClassName to fill value in radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, href, getelementsbyclassname

please.

Have a container on my page filled with links ("link_storage"), where my popup gets links for "value" ("code part bellow"). As you can see it's tied to the IDs, but now I need somehow to switch to class names (for example from old_id_1 to link1_cont).

I was trying to switch to .getElementsByClassName() but didn't succeed.

```js
function onLinkClickCallBack(event) {
  let disableClassName = 'disabled';
  let linkElement = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
  // Don't continue if button is disabled
  if (linkElement.classList.contains(disableClassName)) {
    return false;
  }
}

let inputs = document.getElementsByName('productId');

for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].checked) {
    let value = inputs[i].value;
    document.location.href = document.getElementById(value).href;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="link_storage">

  <span class="link1_cont" id="old_id_1" style="display: none" href="link1"></span>

  <span class="link2_cont" id="old_id_2" style="display: none" href="link2"></span>

  <span class="link3_cont" id="old_id_3" style="display: none" href="link3"></span>

</div>

<fieldset>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="productId" id="radio4" value="zone_link_1" checked>
    <h3>text<br><small>text</small></h3>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="productId" id="radio5" value="zone_link_2">
    <h3>text<br><small>text</small></h3>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="productId" id="radio6" value="zone_link_3">
    <h3>text<br><small>text</small></h3>
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: `href` is a property of `<a>` elements. It has no meaning for `<span>`

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Just use `document.querySelector(".productId:checked")` to get the selected radio button.

Comment: Why do you need to switch to class for getting the element in the `link_storage` container? You only need the value of one element, so an ID should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `zone_` and add `_cont` to the value, and use that as the class name of the element in `link_storage`.

```js
function onLinkClickCallBack(event) {
  let disableClassName = 'disabled';
  let linkElement = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
  // Don't continue if button is disabled
  if (linkElement.classList.contains(disableClassName)) {
    return false;
  }
}

let selectedInput = document.querySelector(".productId:checked");
if (selectedInput) {
  let linkClass = selectedInput.value.replace("zone_") + "_cont";

document.location.href = document.querySelector(`.${linkClass}`).href;
```

```html
<div class="link_storage">
  <span class="link1_cont" id="old_id_1" style="display: none" href="link1"></span>
  <span class="link2_cont" id="old_id_2" style="display: none" href="link2"></span>
  <span class="link3_cont" id="old_id_3" style="display: none" href="link3"></span>
</div>

<fieldset>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="productId" id="radio4" value="zone_link_1" checked>
    <h3>text<br><small>text</small></h3>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="productId" id="radio5" value="zone_link_2">
    <h3>text<br><small>text</small></h3>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="productId" id="radio6" value="zone_link_3">
    <h3>text<br><small>text</small></h3>
  </label>
</fieldset>
```